# Send messages via SOCKETIO encrypted differently to each user in the room using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, socket.io, cryptojs

I'm using socketio in my node.js api, where I have a few dozen connected clients where I send a lot of data per second. In this model I use the command `socket.to(room).emit('message', msg)`, my objective is to send this encrypted data using SECRET and IV (using crypto.js with algorithm aes-256-cbc), where SECRET is the same for all (server side and client), and the IV is different for each user.

Basically I need to encrypt the data sent differently for each user in the room without compromising the performance of the api (runs on a t2.micro ec2 instance in aws). I thought of looping through all the users in that room, and sending a message to each one, but I don't know if that could be costly, I send at least 1 message per second to dozens of users

Comment: Hello @Lucas016! Would you mind translating your title to English so people can find your question in English? If you want to, there is also a Portuguese Stack Overflow community. You could post your question there in Portuguese as well .

Comment: automatic browser translation! Adjusted!

Comment: I´d say: give it a try and see... ! That it will be "costly" times the amount of messages is something that you cant prevent if you want to do it this way

Comment: another approach might be to make the connecting to the room itself with key-auth individually by user while having all messages using same for all as all users already authenticated individually. Because i dont really see the purpose why "the same messages with the same content should be encrypted differently"